# How do i change a pivot table from grand total to average?

Tags: average, webdatarocks

Good afternoon, it is necessary that in the end there is not a sum, but the average of all values. Is it possible to implement this functionality?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In WDR, there is no clear way to make an average grand total if subtotal values contain the sum aggregations.
But you can change the text in grand total cells with the customizeCell  function to make it contain an average value.
Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WDR</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link href="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.toolbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.js"></script>
    <div id="wdr"></div>
    <script>
        var pivot = new WebDataRocks({
            container: "#wdr",
            toolbar: true,
            customizeCell: customize,
            report: {
                dataSource: {
                    filename: "https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/data/data.csv"
                }
            }
        });

        function customize(cell,data) {
            if(data.isGrandTotalRow) {
                cell.text = data.value / (data.rowIndex - 1);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```